# Square divided by absolute value

Tags: absolute-value

First time posting on Math SE, with kind of a basic algebra question.

**Question**
Does the relation:

$$\dfrac{(ab)^2}{|ab|} = \left|ab\right|$$

with $a,b \in \mathbb{R_{\ne 0}}$ always hold?

It seems trivial to me, but Wolfram Alpha gives me a strange answer because it specifies that this is True assuming $a,b$ are positive.

**Reasoning**
No matter what sign $a,b$ have, we have that $(ab)^2 > 0$ and $\left|ab\right| > 0$. Thus their ratio is greater than zero, and the magnitude of that ratio is exactly $ab$ with a positive sign, so $\left|ab\right|$.

Is what I said correct? If so, is this question a completely useless one? Sorry for the occasionally bad English!

*Edit*: formatted equations as suggested by Frentos

Comment: Hmmn, wlog for $a, b \in \mathbb{C}$ one could argue that $a^{2}b^{2} < 0$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! See [this guide](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for how to write equations on this site. \dfrac makes larger, easier to read fractions and \left| \right| gives nicer absolute values.

Comment: @Bacon No, try $a=b=i$ (or any case when $a^2b^2$ is not even real).

Comment: @Did - fair point, my comment meant to reflect that in *some cases* this could be true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement about Wolfram is not quite correct. It gives various alternate forms for this expression, two of which are:

1. $ab$ **assuming $a$ and $b$ are positive**
2. $ab\,sgn(a)\,sgn(b)$

(2) is equivalent to $|ab|$

See [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=simplify+%28a*b%29%5E2%2F%7Ca*b%7C)

Comment: Indeed, I overlooked the $ab \; sgn(a) \; sgn(b)$ answer! I'll accept this one because it points out that Wolfram was right.

Answer (score 0):

For real numbers this is always true because the square of a real number equals the square of its absolute value, and in particular $(ab)^2=|ab|^2.$ Perhaps Wolfram has reservations because it considers the possibility of complex numbers?